# Evaluating values from a indexed ParametricNDSolve solution in parallel

Tags: parallelization

I have a `ParametricNDsolve` solution for a differential equation for a huge system given by `s1`. I have no problem in evaluating the value using the solution. It's, in fact, speeding up the process using Parallel cores.

I have represented the variables by `a, b, c` and  `d`, some of which are indexed by  `j`, and the parameters are `g, n1`and `n2`.
My attempt is to create a table of all the required variables and replace `s1` to them as in `Tab1`and finally evaluate `t` shown by `Tab2`

```
Tab1 = Table[ Table[Table[{a[j, t][g, n1, n2], b[j, t][g, n1, n2], 
   c[g, n1, n2][t], d[g, n1, n2][t]}, {j, 1, 2}], {g, 1, 3, 1}], {n1, 1, 4}, {n2, 1, 4}] /. s1; (*first step*)

Tab2=Tab1/.t->12 (say)
```

So,`Tab1` is only a replacement of the solution `s1` to the given variables `a, b, c` and `d`, which takes me more time to evaluate than `Tab2`. Is there any way I can parallel map or parallelEvaluate Tab1 using all cores available such that `s1` is mapped to the table of variables simultaneously in parallel

Comment: Your nested tables are equivalent to a single table: `Tab1 = Table[{a[j, t][g, n1, n2], b[j, t][g, n1, n2], c[g, n1, n2][t], d[g, n1, n2][t]}, {n1, 1, 4}, {n2, 1, 4}, {g, 1, 3, 1}, {j, 1, 2}];`

Answer (score 1):

Since your `Table` is 5 levels deep to an element we can do this:

```
Tab0 = Table[{a[j, t][g, n1, n2], b[j, t][g, n1, n2], c[g, n1, n2][t], d[g, n1, n2][t]},
 {n1, 1, 4}, {n2, 1, 4}, {g, 1, 3, 1}, {j, 1, 2}];

Tab1 = ParallelMap[# /. s1 &, Tab0, {5}];
```

It might also work at 4 levels deep too - you'd want to experiment to choose the right level that offers the best performance.

I am assuming s1 is a proper rule in a list of the form `{LHS -> RHS}`. Of course there is no guarantee this will be faster.

We could also do the replacement inside the `Table` during construction without needing the `Map` at all, and this would save memory:

```
Tab1 = ParallelTable[{
 a[j, t][g, n1, n2],
 b[j, t][g, n1, n2],
 c[g, n1, n2][t],
 d[g, n1, n2][t]} /. s1,
 {n1, 1, 4}, {n2, 1, 4}, {g, 1, 3, 1}, {j, 1, 2}];
```

Comment: @finity Thank you for your time. I did think one of this idea before. So, when I perform the calculation for my `Tab1` code of the question, it gives the value in 88 secs. Now, for both these suggestions you mentioned below the process keeps running and doesn't evaluate. (ParallelTable works for other random problems)

Comment: Without knowing more about what `s1` and the functions `a,b,c,d` really are, I cannot know why it's taking so long.

Comment: Yes I can understand. I will try to create a sample problem to see if it works. If same issue persists I will update my question. Thank you

Comment: @Rupesh, did this solve your problem? Did you get better performance?

Comment: I did a separate solutions `s1` for `a` and `b` and `s2` for `c` and `d`. Also, for `s1` I had to do
`soln[g1_, n1_, n2_][t_] := Through[s1[g1, n1, n2]@t]`. For `s2` it wasn't required. It works this way.